# How do I display my timer in my SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The score of my game depends on the time you have stayed alive. Although my output log displays the timer counting up, the SKLabelNode stays at 0 on the screen.

```
    self.scoreText.text = "0"
    self.scoreText.fontSize = 60
    self.scoreText.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 500)
    self.scoreText.text = String(self.score)
    self.addChild(self.scoreText)
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("scoreIncrease") , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
// end didMoveToView
func scoreIncrease (){
    score++
    println(score)
}
```

Why does scoreText remain at 0 on the game scene? Thanks in advance for the help and I can respond tomorrow with any other info you may need to help out!

Comment: If the answer provided solved your question you should consider marking it as correct.

Comment: Alright, sorry I'm new but thanks for the tip. Is it fixed now?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure @Brennan Adler will appreciate it :) I just thought I should mention it because you commented that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are continuously updating the value of score on the timer, you aren't updating the text on your `LabelNode`. All you have to do is update the text within your `func scoreIncrease()`

```
func scoreIncrease (){
score++
self.scoreText.text = String(self.score)
println(score)
}
```

Comment: Awesome that was easier than I expected! Thanks so much!